# why would anyone alter a column twice leaving it as it began?

Tags: t-sql

I'm looking at code someone has written and the first thing they are doing on a script is to alter a column to

```
    alter column column_1 decimal(12,0)

    alter column column_1 varchar(30)

    alter column column_2 decimal(12,0)

    alter column column_2 varchar(30)
```

the fields are originally Varchar 30 in the table and I am curious as to why someone would do this? I cannot think of any reason but I'm sure it must be something obvious I am overlooking.

Comment: BTW, brief example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0254f/3/3

Comment: Thanks a mill. makes perfect sense now :)

Comment: this process would also remove not null constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases (depending on how the values were inserted) you may want to normalize the information in the column. Casting to a decimal has formatting repercussions, but also leaves it as a numeric field. So the author decided to cast it once (apply formatting) then cast it back (for whatever reason).

See [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0254f/3/3).

alternatively they could have just run an `UPDATE` script which results in [the same outcome](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0254f/5/2). I'm not *that* fluent in optimization of SQL, but there may be performance benefits to performing a column alteration over an update. Or, as @t-clausen.dk mentions, there are implications with regards to constraints that the author may have wanted. Either way, it was the authors decision to go this route (for whatever reason s/he had).

So, to illustrate, a table that originates looking like:

```
ID  VAL
1   123
2   123.45
3   .123
4   12.34567
```

After the two alters (or an update), you'd end up with:

```
ID  VAL
1   123
2   123
3   0
4   12
```